# Sending a message 5 minutes after a command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So im trying to do my discord bot send a message 5 minutes after someone send a command, but when someone use the command it start sending the message every minute, thats the code

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content === "!command") { 
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
            client.channels.get("493228844896092162")
                .send("123")
                .catch(console.error);
        }, 1 * 5000); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` takes the arguments of a function and a set number of milliseconds on which to trigger.

The correct interval would be

`setInterval(function(){}, 5 * 60000)`

This is 5x60 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Your interval seems to be incorrect. setInterval expects interval to be in milliseconds.

```
1 * 5000 -> 5sec
```

You need to update that to

```
5 * 60 * 1000 -> 5 mins
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd code it like this:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    if (message.content === "!command") { 
        var interval = setInterval (function () {
try {
            var meme = client.channels.get("493228844896092162")
                meme.send("123")
                } catch (error) {
console.log(error.stack);
        }, 5 * 60000); 
    }
});
```